# How can I simplify this bitwise equation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How can i simplify this equation from this

```
(x1^y1)&(x2^y2)=(x1^y1)
```

to this

```
y2=( (x1^y1) | x1) ^ x1
```

where `^` is xor, `|` is or and `&` is and operations respectively.

Thanks.

Comment: It could be more a question for the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), using `logic` the tag in it.

Comment: Are you sure that `x2` vanishes? Simplest solution is to write a truth table with 16 entries for the 4 variables. Then for each entry, where the first equation holds, also the second equation must be true. If not, the second equation cannot be derived from the first one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When

```
x1 = y1 = false
x2 = y2 = true
```

the first equation holds (`false = false`), but not the second (`true = false`).

You cannot simplify the first to the second equation.

Comment: The question is tagged [bitwise-operators](/tags/bitwise-operators/Info): So assume bitwise operators (I assume even the `=` to be bitwise).